# Cookie not sent with the websocket request

Tags: android

In our app, we are using API level 19. But for android version 5 (lollipop) and above, no cookies are sent with the websocket request. We are not sure what is causing this issue. Kindly suggest solution.

Earlier it was working properly, from 1st week of august we got this issue.

Comment: Please update the question with the error that you are getting; if no errors then at least the logging informations which related to the question. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Please share code snippet. I also landed same trouble while using jetty.

It might be you are using incorrect api